# How to remove unused CSS Error that not live in the project?

Tags: css, performance, performance-testing, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I tested my [site](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bunlongheng.com%2F) using Pagespeed Insights

[image]

I kept getting this error `Remove unused CSS`

> …OOKISvkNn…/styles__ltr.css(www.gstatic.com)

Full Link : https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/OOKISvkNnVD_m_9dreR_1S0n/styles__ltr.css

I'm trying to find and remove it. I globally search for it, and see nothing in my project.

## How do I get rid of that error ?

Comment: you cannot remove, it doesn't belong to your site. It's from Google

Comment: I guess, it is a false positive !